# Table columns displaying vertically instead of horizontally - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

[image: Image of problem]

I'm using Bootstrap classes and trying to display the table horizontally. I have been searching on the net and did not get a solution.

The code snippet of the specific JSP page table is:

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr class="bg-success">
                <th>Photo Thumb</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Condition</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/${product.productId}.png" /> " alt="image"
                             style="width:100%"/></td>
                    <td>${product.productName}</td>
                    <td>${product.productCategory}</td>
                    <td>${product.productCondition}</td>
                    <td>${product.productPrice}</td>
                    <td><a href="<spring:url value="/productList/viewProduct/${product.productId}" />"
                    ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**EDIT 1**
The extra CSS that I have added is as follows:

```
.container-wrapper {
    height: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

.table th {
    text-align: center;
}

.table td {
    text-align: center;
    background: whitesmoke;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: but your `<tr>` and `</tr>` outside your loop

Comment: @Cfreak Still doesn't work!

Comment: try putting your java values inside single quotes, like this for example: <img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/${product.productId}.png' /> " alt="image" style="width:100%"/>

Comment: If that doesn't work than something else is happening like you've included more css in your project other than bootstrap. maybe you have included something like : td {display:block;}

Comment: @partypete25 I do have some extra CSS. However even after removing it from the project, it doesn't seem to affect it. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
.table td {
    display: block;
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/PmZXjz)

Comment and uncomment that display property in the css to see the difference it makes.

Comment: I did and it still doesn't help. Could there be a problem with the Bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Possibly, if it isn't a production ready version. is it a local css file or are you referencing from a cdn? If so, provide the link.

Comment: So I changed  '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">' to just '<table>' and it works alright with the formatting all gone. Just as I add the base table class, the problem is back.

Comment: And it is a local file.

Comment: I did see the codepen example, but somehow it doesn't work on my IDE. I'm using Inteliji Ultimate 14.

Comment: This fix is working. Check this plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/qhXntJoRG4gwNxxAU5SR?p=preview)

Comment: It works. I had to delete the cache of my browser. Thank you. :D